# Using https proxy with Selenium WebDriver ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was able to use a proxy successfully, however the proxy is only applied to `http`, and not `https`. I am using the code below

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("myproxy:8080");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

How can I apply the proxy for both `http` and `https`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. It's done by the code  below

```
proxy.setSslProxy();
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--ignore-ssl-errors");

 switch (ProxyType) // your string variable
            {
                case "HTTP":
                    chromeOptions.AddArgument("--proxy-server=http://" + "192.1.1.1:2338"); //example
                    break;
                case "SOCKS":
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--proxy-server=socks5://" + "192.1.1.1:2338");
                    break;
            }
```